# Ошибка "Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code" в MessageKit

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

Выскакивает ошибка "Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code" из консоли понятно, что есть два одинаковых файла в MessageKit и MessageInputBar с именем "UIView+Extensions.swift" при попытки именить имя файла всплывает ошибка "Не найден файл UIView+Extensions.swift" подскажите, что можно помочь решить эту проблема, заранее благодарю за помощь [image: ![Error-one]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HypSC.png)
[[image: error-two]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbcVU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, вы переместили или переименовали файлы напрямую в finder'e и ссылки побились. Попробуйте удалить эти файлы из проекта и по новой добавить. Меняйте названия файлов и перемещайте их в самом проекте, а не в finder'e.